# InfluxDB query performance on small dataset (5000 rows)

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, influxdb

I was comparing the read performance of 3 kinds of databases as a task irrespective of where the database selected as the best is going to be used. InfluxDB, PostgresSql and Oracle. I know that InfluxDB is a time series database and cannot be used like a conventional database(correct me if I am wrong here) but I still anyway am trying to put this database also in the game of comparison.
So I have used Java spring boot frame work to access these databases from the JPA layer. Below is the code.

**InfluxDB access**

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
influxDB.query(new Query("SELECT * FROM ZRM_ZW1"));
Instant finish = Instant.now();
long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();
```

**Posgres Access**

```
@Autowired
postgresRepository repo;

Instant start = Instant.now();
repo.findAll(); 
Instant finish = Instant.now();
long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();
```

**Oracle access**

```
@Autowired
private OracleRepository customerRepo;

Instant start = Instant.now();
List<OracleData> listCustomers = customerRepo.findAll();
Instant finish = Instant.now();             
long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();
```

Here oracle and posgres JPA is constructed directly from the datasource configuration like below

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prohpet
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/newOrcl
#spring.datasource.username=workuser
#spring.datasource.password=workuser
```

I comment one datasource, test the other.(so for posgres and oracle testing its sorted). and for influxDb I have a different configuration for datasource like below:

```
spring.influx.url=http://127.0.0.1:8086
spring.influx.user=admin
spring.influx.password=a
spring.influx.database=test
```

Which I use it to create a connection to influxDB from springboot as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class InfluxDbConfig {

    @Value("${spring.influx.url:''}")
    private String influxDBUrl;

    @Value("${spring.influx.user:''}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.influx.password:''}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.influx.database:''}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    public InfluxDB influxDB(){
        InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxDBUrl, userName, password);
        try {

            influxDB.setDatabase(database)
                    .enableBatch(100,2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            influxDB.setRetentionPolicy("autogen");
        }
        influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.BASIC);
        return influxDB;
    }
}
```

Important Note : in any of the databases there was no indexing done and datetime values where stored as varchar. And in Influx, the time column was filled with continuous days such that each row in influxDb was of one day (I made this from excel and imported as csv to influxDB via telegraph plugin) sample data shown below,

```
time                TagName  
----                -------  -------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ---------- ------ ----------- ----------- -------- ----------- ----    ----     -------
1136160000000000000          7        04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136246400000000000          8        04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136332800000000000          9        04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136419200000000000          10       04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136505600000000000          11       04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136592000000000000          12       04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
1136678400000000000          13       04-12-2021   rrrr          fff           sss        JJJ   wqwqw       vbb         wdjeio   ttrrr       fromCSV test.csv newTag
```

**SO THE QUESTION IS ::**
In the setup, when I have done the read operation testing for a data of 5000 rows (in all DB test cases) I get the result as Influx DB being the slowest with avg read time of over 150 ms whereas postgres was the best with 18ms.
That said, in my understanding, I was hoping influxDB would perform the best but I was amazed at the results. As per my study from various sources on the internet I understand that InfluxDb gives great read performances on huge datasets but in my test results it proved differently. I just want to know if I am missing some basic tunings on influxDB that showed me these results ? some basic protocol that I have not followed on influxDb ? or the way I am accessing InfluxDB (via the custom config instead of using the datasource of springboot ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"InfluxDb gives great read performances on huge datasets"* - that talks about having trillions of records and requesting maybe 10 specific ones based on some time criteria, you perform a query that has nothing to do with that performance claim. Specifically a `findAll` request is the request that is the least useful in determining the performance because you will never run that query in production basically ever. You need to test the performance for the queries that you are actually interested in (and then maybe have a few million records), otherwise the results are completely worthless.

Comment: I just wanted to compare the performance with each other (databases). And hence I used the findAll. Just to get a first glance into which one is better. I guess you will still say that it is of no use doing this way. Right ?

Comment: If one was *better* than the other two, then the other two would not exist. "*better*" always needs context and specific requirements and context, etc. - and you are lacking that. For querying 500 records in a findAll manner an eagerly loaded pure file probably has the best performance (<1ms instant result) but of course a findAll is not the actual query performance you will be interested in. Yes, doing a performance test this way is of absolutely no use because you are not actually testing any *relevant* performance.